# TF2, graph mode very slow against eager mode

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I'm trying to find a way to have a TF model run fast in Graph mode in TF2.3. It seems like the speed i'm getting is very much slower than what's achievable in Eager mode which is unexpected. Here's a simple example (my actual model is more complicated but the effect is similar).

You can paste the below in a script and run with either "2000 1" or "2000 0" as arguments (meaning in Eager or Graph mode respectively). I'm getting at least 10x slower execution in Graph mode. As you can see i run the function twice with the same arguments, so presumably all the preliminary work (tracing and god know what else) should only happen on the first run.

Can anybody please tell me what i'm doing wrong? Eg is there a faster way? Thanks!!!

```
import tensorflow as tf
import datetime
import random
import sys

random.seed(123)

size = int(sys.argv[1])
eager = int(sys.argv[2])

print ("Running TF timing scrupt with size =", size, "eager mode", ("on" if eager else "off"))

if not eager: tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()

a = tf.constant([[random.random() for i in range(size)] for j in range(size)])
b = tf.constant([[random.random() for i in range(size)] for j in range(size)])

@tf.function
def mulX(a, b):
    c = a
    for j in range(40):
        c = c * b
    return tf.math.reduce_sum(c)

if not eager:
    sess = tf.compat.v1.Session()

print ("before 1st run", datetime.datetime.now())
res = tf.math.reduce_sum(mulX(a, b))
if not eager: res = res.eval(session = sess)
print (res)
print ("after 1st run", datetime.datetime.now())

print ("before 2nd run", datetime.datetime.now())
res = tf.math.reduce_sum(mulX(a, b))
if not eager: res = res.eval(session = sess)
print (res)
print ("after 2nd run", datetime.datetime.now())
```

Comment: Forgot to say, i'm measuring and interested in CPU performance

Comment: I was curious because I myself have had similar issues. So I just took your code and ran it on my machine. It does not seem to happen. Here the results  Running TF timing scrupt with size = 10000 eager mode on
before 1st run 2020-12-26 08:00:23.953085
tf.Tensor(1220465.8, shape=(), dtype=float32)
after 1st run 2020-12-26 08:00:26.505519
before 2nd run 2020-12-26 08:00:26.506020
tf.Tensor(1220465.8, shape=(), dtype=float32)
after 2nd run 2020-12-26 08:00:28.914105

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Just to confirm, do you see the same behaviour difference between eager mode and graph (aka not-eager) mode, what your timing there?

Comment: @AlexeyS, Does [Why is Graph 4x slower than Eager on large model? (TF 2.3.0)](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/42429) may help you. Thanks!